# Why does clang++ report a structured binding with "value stored to '...' during its initialization is never read"?

Tags: c++, clang++, c++17, structured-bindings

I have the following test case:

```
testcase("[room] exits") {
    auto [center, east, north, south, west] = make_test_rooms();

    check_eq(center->east(), east);
    check_eq(center->north(), north);
    check_eq(center->south(), south);
    check_eq(center->west(), west + 1);
}
```

When I compile it, clang++ (clang version 5.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_501/final)) reports:

```
room.cpp:52:7: note: Value stored to '[center, east, north, south, west]' during its initialization is never read
```

In the code above, `testcase` and `check_eq` are macros defined for [the doctest unit testing package](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) that expand to `DOCTEST_TEST_CASE()` (some kind of self-registering variable+function pair) and `DOCTEST_CHECK_EQ` (basically, "assert a == b", with magic handling).

I know this code is being executed, since the `west + 1` is a deliberately-introduced error. When I run my tests, I get a failure message like this one:

```
===============================================================================
/.../room.cpp(51)
TEST CASE:  [room] exits

/.../room.cpp(57) ERROR!
  CHECK_EQ( center->west(), west + 1 )
with expansion:
  CHECK_EQ( 0x00007fd6f1d011a0, 0x00007fd6f1d011f8 )
```

As far as I can see, I am using all of the values in the structured binding: `center` appears on the left of my checks, and `north, south, east, west` appear on the right. Why is clang++ reporting something as "never read"?

**Update**

Here is code that reproduces the issue. I run this command line (taken from the output of `make VERBOSE=1` and reduced):

```
$ /opt/local/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --tidy=/opt/local/bin/clang-tidy --source=test.cpp -- /opt/local/bin/clang++  -g -std=gnu++1z -o test.cpp.o -c test.cpp
/Users/austin/Code/agb/test.cpp:12:7: warning: Value stored to '[a, b, c]' during its initialization is never read [clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores]
        auto [a,b,c] = foo();
             ^
/Users/austin/Code/agb/test.cpp:12:7: note: Value stored to '[a, b, c]' during its initialization is never read
```

I used this source file as `test.cpp`:

```
#include <tuple>

static std::tuple<int, int, int>
foo()
{
    return {1,2,3};
}

bool
test()
{
    auto [a,b,c] = foo();

    return a<b and b<c;
}
```

Comment: false positive?

Comment: @bolov I hope that's the case, I guess. But the whole thing is new enough to me that I'm willing to invite much-more-clueful people to explain what's really going on.

Comment: clang bug, please report. Note that it's telling you that the underlying object isn't read, not each of its destructured components.

Comment: For completeness can you post enough code so that someone else could copy-paste it into a compiler to reproduce it, and also the full clang warning?

Comment: @AndyG: updated

Comment: @AustinHastings: Thanks. What happens if you remove the `--tidy` option from your build?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, since there's no mention of --tidy in any of my files. But when I strip it from the command line, I get "__run_co_compile missing command to run. Looking for one or more of the following:" (plus a list).

Answer (score -2):

In the [clang analyzer faq](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html) this is considered a common false positive:

> **Q: How do I tell the static analyzer that I don't care about a specific dead store?**
>
> When the analyzer sees that a value stored into a variable is never
>   used, it's going to produce a message similar to this one:
>
> ```
> Value stored to 'x' is never read
> ```
>
> You can use the (void)x; idiom to acknowledge that there is a dead
>   store in your code but you do not want it to be reported in the
>   future.

There's no use reasoning about why it's a false positive. The warning can disappear/reappear with subtle changes to the code or between versions of Clang.

Comment: Where is the dead store in the question?